# matplotlib figure won't show when Python is run from VS Code integrated terminal

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I'm experiencing an issue while using VS Code to debug Python files. It seems that since last updating VS Code  matplotlib figures have stopped being displayed after calls of `plt.show()`. There are no errors reported, and the script continues to execute as though the call had been successful, so I'm not sure what the cause is.

Initially I thought it was perhaps something to do with the backend, so I tried running in various Python environments with different `matplotlib.plot` backends and Python versions but no success.

My only though is that it's possible VS Code settings are overriding the backend or environment somehow and might be causing this behaviour?

Comment: If you run your script outside of VS Code, does the problem go away? If not, please include a [simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with your question.

Comment: Yes, the issue is present specifically while using VS Code, and nowhere else. There's nothing I can really provide as an example other than literally anything that would normally produce a graph. Even something as simple as `plt.plot([1, 2], [3, 4])` followed by `plt.show()`

Answer (score 10):

I was facing the same problem inside an Anaconda's virtual environment. I created a simple script (below), when running on Ubuntu's Terminal the plot appeared, but on VSCode's Terminal the plot didn't open and the script finished.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3], [10, 20, 30])
plt.show()
```

I solved by opening VSCode Settings (JSON) and changing "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv" to true. I guess you should add this option if it's not there.

Found the solution on other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63368392/2014507 (credits to [Jiang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4886243/jiang))

Comment: Hmmm, I think this must be a different problem, as `terminal.integrated.inheritEnv` is already set to True for me.

Comment: This worked for me, although I had to set the "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv" to True as the last line in my JSON settings. Don't understand why, but it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you're on the remote server and VS code is on the local, try adding `ForwardX11 yes` in your `.ssh/config` file.

Answer (score -1):

set

"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": true,

in your user settings

#and# then don't forget to put

plt.show()

at the end of your python file. Without plt.show() your images will not be dispayed.

Answer (score -2):

while accessing the file from terminal in VSCode, Save the plot, then it will be visible
plt.savefig('file_name.png')

Comment: Thank you, I am aware that plot images can be save, but that is not the question I am asking, and is not useful when dealing with cases where the figure should be displayed via a `plt.show()` command.