# VSCode cannot switch matplotlib backend: ImportError: Cannot load backend 'Qt5Agg' which requires the 'qt5' interactive framework

Tags: python, matplotlib, visual-studio-code

I just want to plot by running Python in VSCode but in turn out failure. I cannot switch the backend from agg to Qt5Agg. However, I can easily do so in the terminal out of VSCode...

The problem in VSCode integrated terminal is shown below, where I have tried various solutions but failed..:

```
(base) user@user:~/test$ export MPLBACKEND=Qt5Agg
(base) user@user:~/test$ python
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 16:21:59) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib
>>> print("Using:",matplotlib.get_backend())
Using: Qt5Agg
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot([1,2,3], [10, 20, 30])
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fe26b403d00>]
>>> plt.show()
>>> print("Using:",matplotlib.get_backend())
Using: agg
>>> plt.switch_backend('Qt5Agg')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/zslwyuan-laptop/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib-3.3.0rc1+627.gff821ba32-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 268, in switch_backend
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Cannot load backend 'Qt5Agg' which requires the 'qt5' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running
>>>
```

Any help will be really appreciated. !!

Comment: Try to use'pip list' to check whether'PyQt5' has been successfully installed in the current environment of VSCode.I tested it and it showed no issue. What was the result of reloading VSCode?

Comment: Thanks Jill, I work out with a solution accepted in this thread! ^_^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem. Changing "terminal.integrated.inheritEnv" to true in settings solved the problem. I don't know why and have not yet met any side effects.

Comment: Thanks! It works! 0-0 It seems that inherited settings will enforce Python to use 'agg' backend to prevent it from popping up windows.

Comment: It seems that VS code can't pickup the same back-end as terminal, it helps and big thanks!